# compute the marginal pdf $P(x)$ of $X$ and $ P(y)$ of $Y$ given the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ in the table.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

A discrete $(X,Y)$ probability distribution is given by the following table:

[image]

The task is to compute the marginal pdf $P(x)$ of $X$ and $ P(y)$ of $Y$.

**MY CALCULATIONS:**

The range $R_x$ of $X$ is $0,1,4$

The range $R_y$ of $Y$ is $0,2,3,5$

According to the definition of marginal pdf we have:

$P(x)=$ $\sum_{y\in R_y}^{} f(x,y)$; where $f(x,y)$ is given by table.

This is where I get stuck. I don't know how to evaluate the above equation further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Example: $P(X=1)=f(1,0)+f(1,2)+f(1,3)+f(1,5)=\cdots$

Comment: That will result in 3 parts. i.e: $P(X=0)$ $P(X=1)$  and $P(X=4)$. How am I supposed to find $E(X)$ then? Will it be: $E(X)=0*P(X=0)+1*P(X=1)+4*P(X=4)$

Comment: Yes, that calculation gives you the expectation of rv $X$.

Comment: I have one more question Sir, and it the last part of this question which I didn't mention previsously in this post. It is to find conditional probability distribution $P(Y/X=x)$ and create rv $E(Y/X)$ and then calculate $E(E(X/Y)).$ By conditional probability distribution $P(Y/X=x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{P(x)}$. From here how do I move forward since $f(x,y)$ is in form of table and I cant find a way to perform division here. Last, How I define $E(Y/X)$ as a rv? I have thought whole day but cant figure out. Any guidance will be appreaciate.

Comment: $\Pr(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{\Pr(Y=y,X=x)}{\Pr(X=x)}=\frac{f(x,y)}{P(x)}$ is correct. Then define a function $g$ on $\{0,1,4\}$ by stating that: $$g(x):=\mathbb E[Y|X=x]=\sum_y\Pr(Y=y|X=x)$$where on RHS $y$ ranges over $\{0,2,3,5\}$. Then $g(X)$ is a random variable and this rv is denoted as $\mathbb E[Y|X]$. Because you know the distribution of $X$ you can calculate the expectation of $g(X)=\mathbb E[Y|X]$. If you make no mistakes you will find that calculation of $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y|X]]$ gives the same final result as calculation of $\mathbb EY$, so that can be used as a nice sanity check.

Comment: Can't we explicity solve for $Pr(Y=y|X=x)?$ what you have written is the expression just like me, which is not evaluated.

Comment: Yes, you can (and you should). The expression just indicates how to do that.